# How to remove spacing in Open Editor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to remove the spacing in the 'Open Editor'? Where do I need to tweak this?

vscode open editor spacing

[image: vscode open editor spacing]

I tried searching in VSCode settings but all it has is the actual editor.

Comment: Not sure if that is even possible, why would you even want to remove it?

Comment: that gives you 1 character extra space on a line, not a big deal, if you really want it gone, use **Custom CSS**, locate the CSS selector and set the margin/padding to 0

Comment: @LucasdeRijke i have a small screen, file names (with path) are cut off, and i dont want to adjust so i could have more space for my editor

Comment: @rioV8 where do i set this?

Comment: can't you just zoomout with ctrl -

Comment: spacing still looks off to me, what is the purpose of the spacing anyway when other notes/tags are after the filenames (e.g M for modified)?

Comment: The spacing is there to serve as an indent of your main folder.

Comment: I've checked with groups and the indent is too much for me

Comment: use `Ctrl+B` to hide the Bar when you don't need it while typing in the file